# Set android screen resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

I'm trying to alter the default screen resolution of the Android emulator (and by extension, the Android device) to work at 1700x1200.  In other words, I need the screen to be able to display unique points over that range.

I have set the dimensions in my layout file, yet the device still defaults to 320x480.  I've set different dpi densities, but to no avail.

Any help would be great, even just a direction to explore.

EDIT:  Thanks for the two responses.  I guess my question wasn't clear - I understand that the top resolution for the device is fixed, but I need to scale the screen to display with finer granularity than just 640X850 (which I believe is the highest resolution).  I understand you can set dpi density from 120-240, but I need to know how to set the scaling functionality to simulate a screen of 1700x1200.  My guess is that it will have to be done by my code, but I would prefer for the platform to auto-scale it down for me.  This may not be possible, but I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Android SDK 2.0 or 2.1 you can create an AVD with a custom resolution. If you want you can also run the emulator with the -skin argument, for instance emulator -skin 1700x1200 and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

May be i'm not completely understand that. You want physical device such as ADP1 phone for example, to have 1700x1200 ? If it that you want - i have some bad news - if you look at any device spec you'll see resolution listed. It's there because it characteristic of physical screen. It can't be changed.

Comment: BTW - layout file has nothing to do with device or emulator resolution.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that the device is physical limited to particular resolutions, but I also believed that the android platform can scale points from a larger resolution to fit the current one.  This probably goes to density of pixels and the like, but I was just wondering if there was a platform-based tool that could scale on-the-fly to handle points beyond the current resolution (in other words, to scale a 1700x1200 canvas to the current resolution).